# Convert text document to numpy array of ASCII numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, utf-8, nlp, ascii

I have a large plain text document (UTF-8) that contains letters, numbers, spaces, and special characters etc.

I want to convert all the individual characters in the text document into numbers, and then represent the document as a numpy array.

Can I use the inbuilt python ord() function for this?

My understanding is that it returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character, but only takes on in one character at a time and I'm wondering if there's a better way to convert a large text document to numbers.

Or can I just iterate through the entire document with the ord() function?

**edit**

I basically want to do something exactly like this! but natively in python https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-ascii

This is what I currently have

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return ",".join(str(ord(char)) for char in text)

with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

convert_to_ascii(data)

values = [int(i) for i in x.split(',')] 

array = np.array(values)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should skip the `",".join()` part, as it is unnecessary here.

Instead, you can simply create the `values` list in the `convert_to_ascii()` function:

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    return [ord(char) for char in text)

values = convert_to_ascii(data)
array = np.array(values)
```

However, even the intermediate list is unnecessary, since a numpy array can be constructed from an iterable. And it can do so efficiently if you know the lenght in advance. And you do: it's the length of the string. Thus:

```
def convert_to_ascii(text):
    for char in text:
        yield ord(char)

array = np.fromiter(convert_to_ascii(data), count=len(data))
```

And this `convert_to_ascii` function can be replaced with a call to the built-in `map` function:

```
array = np.fromiter(map(ord, data), count=len(data))
```

By the way, if your file is encoded with UTF-8, you should probably open the file with the `encoding="utf-8"` parameter to be sure. The default value is platform/locale dependent.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on the same issue, and came across a much simpler and faster technique, demonstrated below:

```
import numpy as np

text = 'abcABC00'

letter_array = np.fromiter(text, dtype='c')
letter_array.shape, letter_array.dtype

    ((8,), dtype('S1'))


ascii_array = letter_array.view(np.int8)
ascii_array.shape, ascii_array.dtype, ascii_array

    ((8,), dtype('int8'), array([97, 98, 99, 65, 66, 67, 48, 48], dtype=int8))
```

I included intermediate values just to show what's going on, but the production code could be reduced to a single line.

```
ascii_array = np.fromiter(text, dtype='c').view(np.int8)
```

Comment: Your last, single line works great, thanks.  My `text` variable is an ndarray slice.  After that assignment, `ndarr1 = ndarr1.astype(numpy.int64)` changes the whole ndarray of numeric strings to integer.